# How do I change the cursor image globally

Tags: javascript, cursor

I've seen many tutorials on this using CSS's "cursor:" property. However, that's mostly for cursors seen when hovering over something. I need to change the cursor universally, throughout the site. I assume this uses Javascript, but I don't know Javascript so I need some help.

**Yes,** I'm aware this is usually a bad design choice, which is why the website I'm doing this for is a joke. It's meant to be a recreation of every 90s site ever.

Just to make it more clear what I want, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9N8Y.png) is the list of images I'm looking to use with the site. I'm wondering how to change the cursor universally, not just on specific elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the CSS cursor property for the html or body tag

```
html {
    cursor: url("hyper.cur"), auto;
}
```

Comment: I need to change the cursor's image, not the actual cursor being used.

Comment: There is a URL option, where you can provide a URL to the cursor you want to use. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```html
<html>
<span style="cursor:auto">auto</span><br>
<span style="cursor:crosshair">cross-hair</span><br>
<span style="cursor:default">default</span><br>
<span style="cursor:e-resize">e-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:grab">grab</span><br>
<span style="cursor:progress">progress</span><br>
<span style="cursor:s-resize">s-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:se-resize">se-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:sw-resize">sw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:help">help</span><br>
<span style="cursor:move">move</span><br>
<span style="cursor:n-resize">n-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:ne-resize">ne-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:nw-resize">nw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:pointer">pointer</span><br>
<span style="cursor:text">text</span><br>
<span style="cursor:w-resize">w-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:wait">wait</span><br>
<span style="cursor:not-allowed">not-allowed</span><br>
<span style="cursor:no-drop">no-drop</span><br>

</html>
```